# How to fix the create's action in a many to many relationships in CRUD Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

good afternoon dead stackoverflow's friends.

My problem is when i want to created a many to many relationship in a scaffold with references inside in, the tables called activities and groups and the references table is permissions my error is in the actions create and edit.

The error says :

> unknown attribute 'groups' for Permission.

```
  # POST /permissions.json
  def create
    @permission = Permission.create(permission_params)
```

the hash is this :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"e9KAgCvqlXJxfsHIUOhapwg7XTJM6x+uEyd229kO+GG6bHJ/iMjywC07u3fwMyzqMSYpm9zSTrbXASSI5TpFzg==",
 "permission"=>{"groups"=>["2"], "activities"=>["1"], "c"=>"0", "r"=>"0", "u"=>"1", "d"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Crear Permisos"}
```

controller

```
class PermissionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_permission, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /permissions
  # GET /permissions.json
  def index
    @permissions = Permission.all
    @activity = Activity.all
    @group = Group.all
  end

  # GET /permissions/1
  # GET /permissions/1.json
  def show
    @activity = Activity.all
    @group = Group.all
  end

  # GET /permissions/new
  def new
    @permission = Permission.new
  end

  # GET /permissions/1/edit
  def edit
    @permission = Permission.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @all_groups = Group.all
    @groups_the_permissions_is_created = @permission.groups.pluck(:id)
    @activities_the_permissions_is_created = @permission.activities.pluck(:id)
  end

  # POST /permissions
  # POST /permissions.json
  def create
    @permission = Permission.create(permission_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @permission.save
        format.html { redirect_to @permission, notice: 'Permission was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @permission }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @permission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /permissions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /permissions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @permission.update(permission_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @permission, notice: 'Permission was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @permission }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @permission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /permissions/1
  # DELETE /permissions/1.json
  def destroy
    @permission.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to permissions_url, notice: 'Permission was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_permission
      @permission = Permission.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def permission_params
      params.require(:permission).permit( :c, :r, :u, :d, :groups => [], :activities => [])
    end

end
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180122191652) do

  create_table "activities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "memberships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_group_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "permissions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "activity_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.boolean "c"
    t.boolean "r"
    t.boolean "u"
    t.boolean "d"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["activity_id"], name: "index_permissions_on_activity_id"
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_permissions_on_group_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer "failed_attempts", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.string "name", default: "", null: false
    t.string "work", default: "", null: false
    t.string "bank"
    t.string "type_of_bank_account"
    t.integer "bank_account_number", limit: 20
    t.string "email_paypal"
    t.integer "identification_card", limit: 8
    t.integer "phone_number", limit: 20
    t.integer "house_number", limit: 20
    t.string "skype"
    t.text "abilities"
    t.text "languages"
    t.string "invitation_token"
    t.datetime "invitation_created_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_sent_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_accepted_at"
    t.integer "invitation_limit"
    t.integer "invited_by_id"
    t.string "invited_by_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["invitation_token"], name: "index_users_on_invitation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1 align="center">Creación de permisos</h1>
<div class="col s12 m12 l12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content hoverable">
            <%= render 'form', permission: @permission %>
            <%= link_to 'Back', permissions_path , :class => 'waves-effect waves-light btn permissions-submit'%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

    <p>
      <strong>Activity:</strong>
      <%= @permission.activity.name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Group:</strong>
      <%= @permission.group.name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>C:</strong>
      <%= @permission.c %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>R:</strong>
      <%= @permission.r %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>U:</strong>
      <%= @permission.u %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>D:</strong>
      <%= @permission.d %>
    </p>

    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_permission_path(@permission) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', permissions_path %>

_form.html.erb

<%= form_with(model: permission, local: true) do |form| %>
<% if permission.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(permission.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this permission from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
    <% permission.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<span class="card-title"><i class="material-icons left">assignment_ind</i> Creación de permisos</span>
<%= form.label :Grupos %>
<div class="field">
  <p>
    <%= form.collection_check_boxes :groups, Group.order(:name), :id, :name, :include_hidden => false%>
  </p>
</div>
<%= form.label :Procesos%>
<div class="field">
  <%= form.collection_check_boxes :activities, Activity.order(:name), :id, :name, :include_hidden => false%>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :Permisos%>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= form.check_box :c, id: :permission_c%>
  <%= form.label :c, :class => 'example-class' %>
  <%= form.check_box :r, id: :permission_r %>
  <%= form.label :r %>
  <%= form.check_box :u, id: :permission_u %>
  <%= form.label :u %>
  <%= form.check_box :d, id: :permission_d %>
  <%= form.label :d %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit 'Crear Permisos' , :class => 'waves-effect waves-light btn permissions-submit'%>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Assosiations:

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :permissions
    has_many :groups, through: :permissions
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships 
    has_many :permissions
    has_many :activities, through: :permissions
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end



class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: could you share your form code? i mean new.html.erb

Comment: paste code of `form` partial in your question

Comment: @Gabbar The code is ready now.

Comment: what does permission.rb look like? you probably need to change the `groups` to `group_id` or similar, or an `accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups`, but those are both just guesses without seeing permission.rb

Comment: Please share code of your models or at least association declarations. Also, as @Gabbar pointed out, the actual form would be helpful. Association may be missing or broken in models, but from params I can see that the form needs fixes. In params, it passes ["2"] to "groups"- the array that contains ids that should go to "group_ids" attribute instead. Same with "activities".

Comment: You pasted Activity twice and forgot Permission.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your association between Permission and Group.

Permission belongs_to Group, meaning there is a single group for each permission. But you've built it to expect multiple groups for each permission. The error is telling you there is no method `groups` on an instance of permission because there isnt; there is a `group` method

in your show route, you're doing things correctly by calling `<%= @permission.group.name %>`, but in your edit route you call `@permission.groups` and your create route is failing because the strong params you've set up are expecting many group ids to come in `permit(groups: [])`

this line is breaking

```
# def edit
@groups_the_permissions_is_created = @permission.groups.pluck(:id)
```

and should be something like

```
# def edit
@groups_the_permissions_is_created = @permission.group.id
```

your strong params are breaking because you're permitting `group: []` but should be permitting a single `:group_id`